# is there any api to set the alternative functions for the gpio in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gpio

I am looking to set the alt function for the gpio, i did that by using the hack code

```
#define INP_GPIO(g) *(gpio+((g)/10)) &= ~(7<<(((g)%10)*3))
#define SET_GPIO_ALT(g,a) *(gpio+(((g)/10))) |= (((a)<=3?(a)+4:(a)==4?3:2)<<(((g)%10)*3))
unsigned int *gpio;
gpio = ioremap(GPIO_BASE, SZ_16K);
INP_GPIO(pin);
SET_GPIO_ALT(pin, alt);
iounmap(gpio);
#undef INP_GPIO
#undef SET_GPIO_ALT
```

But now i want it to set the alt function using the api if it is available in the linux.

I searched a lot but i did not find any api.

Can u suggest me something here?

Comment: Clarify what you mean by *"alternative functions for the gpio"*.  GPIO is the acronym for "general-purpose input/output".  GPIO can be one of the possible functions of a multplexed pin.  If the pin is assigned to a peripheral function, then it's no longer a GPIO.  There's a Linux API for GPIO, and none for the pin multiplexing (aka pin control).

Comment: I use one gpio ie gpio2 in my machine driver, initially i set it as output and i will configure my device by using the gpio2 by using the API `gpio_direction_output(GPIO2, 1);` After configuring it, i need to use the same pin as i2c data line, So that i need to set that pin as alt0 function. I searched a lot for API but  i didnt find. Is there any API available or i need to continue with the hack http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24820/i-want-to-set-the-alt-function-for-the-gpio-in-raspberry-pi.

Comment: That's a very unfortunate and innacurate view, especially once you talk about anything but buttoned up, locked  down consumer products.

Comment: *"So that i need to set that pin as alt0 function"* -- You seem to freely interchange the terms *"GPIO"* and *"pin"*.  You shouldn't, because they do refer to different things.  You should study **Documentation/pinctrl.txt** in the Linux kernel source code.  There's sections on *Pin control requests from drivers*, *Drivers needing both pin control and GPIOs* and *Runtime pinmuxing*.

Comment: Yes, we are using the dynamic pinmuxing only. But we did that through the hack code that i shared above. Now i am looking for the API

Comment: Pinctrl is your friend.